# Android studio LogCat encoding russian text

Tags: android, sqlite, unicode, ide, logcat

İ have problem with Logcat (Android studio v 1.2.2), it doesn't show Russian symbols. How can I fix it?

Comment: the same on the terminal when running `logcat` command?

Comment: I use android device monitor, and some menu in the bottom side of android studio, the same problem

Comment: The same problem are now with english letters, what is going on?

Comment: tried `logcat` command (from your terminal window)?

Comment: Where should I type it,

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Comment: where is platform tools in windows 7?

Comment: I found that there is a problem with encoding in SQLite, here is the code

db.execSQL("create table mytable (" +                                     
        "id integer primary key autoincrement,"+"name text," +            
        "people integer,"+"region text"+");");
logcat works good with other strings, the only problem with data from sqlite

Comment: How can I store unicode here?

Comment: It should work just fine,  how do you insert data?

Comment: <pre>String name[]={"Китай","США","Бразилия","Россия",          
  "Япония","Германия","Египет","Италия","Франция","Канада"};
   int people[]={1400,311,195,142,128,82,80,60,66,35};                                                           
   String region[]={"Азия","Америка","Америка","Европа","Азия","Европа","Африка","Европа","Европа","Америка"}  ;
 ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();                   
 for (int i=0;i<name.length;i++){
     cv.put("name",name[i]);
     cv.put("people",people[i]);
     cv.put("region",region[i]);
Log.d(LOG_TAG,"id = "+db.insert("mytable",null,cv));
}</pre>

Comment: Did you try sqlite3 command to see real data in the database?

Comment: Can i make direct quries to sqlite?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sqlite3.html

Comment: also try debugger to inspect `ContentValues cv` before `db.istert` call

Comment: It worked! I reinstalled Android Studio, but what really helped, I guess, that I uninstalled the app to clean db. Maybe there was some bug while creating db,  I don't exactly know the answer still(